# Is there a way to associate data with an MSFlexGrid cell that is not displayed to the user?

Tags: vb6

Say I've got your standard MSFlexGrid. I have an image in a cell that already has a tooltip.

What I want to do is store a string about the image in the cell that's associated with the cell but is not displayed to the end user.

I've been looking at the properties on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227985(v=vs.60).aspx) website but I didn't see anything that would work.

Is this possible? Has anyone done something similar before? I'm not opposed to using properties that were not necessarily designed for data storage in this sense provided they're not being used already, but obviously this is not desirable.

Comment: Have you considered just adding a hidden column to hold the information. We do not use msflexgrids at my work but we use vsflexgrids and thats what we do. Some places in our application attempt to keep arrays of data in sync with the grid but usually this works out poorly when some one goes to make a change.

Comment: Will there be more than one image per row, i.e. are the images only within one column? Because if it's the case, you could look at the RowData property (applies to a whole row). But if you think you would need it more than once per row, then as far as I know MSFlexGrid doesn't provide a way to store per-cell data (other than text or image).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's more than one image per row. (I know, sad). I've been working on using an array / dictionary, but that's not going super smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did for those who may be looking to do the same. It's not elegant, it's not pretty, but it works.

```
Private m_colImageInfo As Collection ' dictionary to store image name Key="Index^m_Tracker Row^Column" Value=IconKey
Private m_colImageInfoSorted As Collection ' Dictionary to store image name Key="Index^FG Row^Column" Value=IconKey
Private m_colSortRowInfo As ACCollection ' How the row changes
```

I have a function, called DoDisplay() that gets called everytime the grid is refreshed or initially displayed.

In it, I clear the m_colSortRowInfo Collection (ACCollection is just a wrapper we've built).

```
  Call m_colSortRowInfo.Clear ' Note ACCollection allows the use of Clear
```

Now in do display we're grabbing data from the model, and get the actual image with the first DoAction call, and then get the image key (unique identifier about the image) with the second call.

```
Set oImage = m_Tracker2.DoAction(TS_ACTION_GET_COL_ICON, lRow, lColumn, False)  'Retrieve the icon image ' get the image
                      sString = m_Tracker2.DoAction(TS_ACTION_GET_COL_ICON, lRow, lColumn, True)
                      If Len(sString) > 0 Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Call m_colSortRowInfo.Add(CStr(.Index & "^" & lRow & "^" & .Col)) ' lets store the old key as a value for later access
                        Call m_colImageInfo.Add(sString, CStr(.Index & "^" & lRow & "^" & .Col))
                        On Error GoTo 0
                      End If
```

Then I add the icon key to m_colImageInfo as the Collection's "item" and the key being the grid Index^m_TrackerRow^Column.

To the m_colSortRowInfo I set the the same value (Index^m_TrackerRow^Column) as the item and then the key is just a simple iterative index.

Now the problem I was encountering was that these images exist in the grid, but I don't know anything about them besides that the cell contains, or doesn't contain an image / text. I need to associate the icon key with the image for reasons irrelevant to this post.

So now, we've gotten the grid, row and column of the model that the image is in, but we don't know where it actually lies in the grid. The column stays the same, but based on how the user has sorted the grid, the rows can change. This is the key challenge.

We have a way to map the model grid row to a specific MSFlexGrid row. I use that in the method below to populate m_colImageInfoSorted, which is the actual representation of each image in the grid.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------
' NAME:         SortImageCollection (PRIVATE)
' DESCRIPTION:  When we first create the flex grid we pull the images from
'               the image provider service and scale them up unfortunately there is
'               no reference to the image that gets back. So what we do is create a
'               collection to keep track of the image location and then send it to
'               the printing class. If the grid has been sorted however, we need to
'               identify where that picture moved too. This sub serves that purpose.
' KEYWORDS:     sort, icon, collection, image
' CALLED BY:    DoDisplay
' PARAMETERS:
'  Index (I,REQ) - FlexGrid index
' RETURNS:      nothing
' ASSUMES:
' SIDE EFFECTS: populates m_colImageInfoSorted with image keys in the fg grid
'               with index passed to the function
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub SortImageCollection(Index As Integer)
  Dim lCnt As Long
  Dim lNumImages As Long
  Dim lColumn As Long
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim lOldRow As Long
  Dim lCurGrid As Long
  Dim sTempIconStr As String
  Dim sOldKey As String
  Dim sNewKey As String

  Set m_colImageInfoSorted = Nothing
  Set m_colImageInfoSorted = New Collection

  With fgFlexGrid(Index)
    For lNumImages = 1 To m_colSortRowInfo.Count                                        ' we will loop over all the images
      lCurGrid = CLng(Piece(m_colSortRowInfo.ItemVar(lNumImages), "^", 1, False))          ' if the grid is the grid we we asked for, then continue
      If (lCurGrid = Index) Then                                                        ' we are just sorting images for this grid
        For lCnt = 1 To m_lPatientRows(Index)
          On Error Resume Next
          lOldRow = CLng(Piece(m_colSortRowInfo.ItemVar(lNumImages), "^", 2, False))       ' get the m_tracker row we stored earlier
          lRow = getRowFromFlexGrid(Index, lCnt)                                        '

          sOldKey = m_colSortRowInfo.ItemVar(lNumImages)                                   ' get the old key
          lColumn = Piece(sOldKey, "^", 3, False)
          sTempIconStr = m_colImageInfo.Item(CStr(Index & "^" & lRow & "^" & lColumn))  '
          sNewKey = CStr(.Index & "^" & lCnt & "^" & lColumn)                           ' get the column, add to new key
          If (Len(sTempIconStr)) > 0 Then                                               ' if we have an image (didn't already remove it)
            Call m_colImageInfoSorted.Add(sTempIconStr, sNewKey)                        ' Add the new image location
          End If
          On Error GoTo 0
        Next lCnt
      End If
    Next lNumImages
  End With
End Sub
```

And wahlah, the call to the sub is all it takes:

```
Call SortImageCollection(Index)
```

I know that the SortImageCollection() sub is not the most efficient. If there is a better way to do this mapping, let me know, I'm interested in the response, but this is working well, and has no apparent slow down from an end user perspective so I'm happy with it.